# Parent and Child Navigation Link Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know what keyword suppose to search for this case.

I have Page A as parent, page A1 A2 A3 as child page of A

I want to show navigation like this

A A1 A2
A3 A4

before content of page

how to solve this case?

Thank you

Comment: Lots of ways to this, could you provide a bit more info and also do you have access to edit theme files? You could use wp_list_pages() or get_pages() or a wp_nav_menu() with a nav created in admin.

Comment: yes, i am able to edit theme files, I want to show only several pages so need to create to shortcode so I need to call shortcode for pages with navigation along with parent, child and siblings

Comment: Any of the functions I've mentioned above should sit your purposes.